# Journey Builder status report

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, reporting

I think the answer is no but wanted to throw this question out to the community to cover my bases.

Is there a report or other functionality that will give me the *status* of Journey Builder journeys?

In an effort to validate some data prior to my Automation SQL running and inserting records into the journey I paused the journey and automation to ensure no records would be inserted or emails would deploy until the validation occurred.  Of course, when the validation was done I restarted the automation but NOT the journey so while the automation ran successfully and the records were inserted, nothing happened. Ugh.

Obviously pausing the journey is overkill and unnecessary since the automation was paused, however, this has led to the question "how can we ensure that all journeys that should be running are running?

Aside from a report detailing emails sent as part of all journeys and using that as a proxy, are there any other options?

TIA.

Comment: I would suggest looking into the Digital Command Center if you're on Slack. Otherwise, you could build something custom where you retrieve the status of your journeys using SSJS and send yourself an email if one them is not active.

Answer (score 0):

There's a data view table that contains some system info that contains the info you are looking for.

Have a look at the _journey data view table. If you have Query Studio it makes it very easy, if not you can just create an automation to run and dump the data in a data extension.

In Query Studio or a SQL Query automation activity, use the following:

```
SELECT
j.VersionID,
j.JourneyID,
j.JourneyName,
j.VersionNumber,
j.CreatedDate,
j.LastPublishedDate,
j.ModifiedDate,
j.JourneyStatus
FROM _Journey AS j
```

j.JourneyStatus is going to have the status you are looking for and should show you if it is Running, Deleted, Stopped, Paused, or Draft.

I would recommend to familiarize yourself with the various data views SFMC has, as these can be very powerful resources to use. You can find more details here- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_views.htm&language=en_US&type=5